# How to fix "IndentationError: expected an indented block" and "EOF error: EOF reading a line"?

Tags: python-3.x

The EOF, identation error is coming when I execute the code in leetcode evironment but in jupyter it is working perfectly. It has been executed in jupyter.

I tried try, except statements

```
List=[]
        n=int(input("Enter no: elem  "))
        for i in range(0,n):
            elem=int(input())
            List.append(elem)
        print(List)
```

I expected the output in leetcode. but I got output in Jupyter.

Comment: This is a leet code problem add-sum

Comment: I'm hesitant to fix your formatting since this is an indentation error. Please format it correctly and post a [mcve] that shows the problem. If I assume the indent issue here is a typo, there isn't anything seemingly wrong with this code.

Comment: I added a code fence so the indentation is untouched. Is the first line actually like that in your real code?